# Multiset - double binomial coefficient?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, multinomial-coefficients

In a recent question I have seen for the first time the symbol in my life:

$$\left(\!\!{n\choose k}\!\!\right)$$

Practically why this symbol is used and what are the benefits in the mathematical-informatics area? I didn't really understand it much having given it a quick read. Could it be useful for me as an application of a high school concept or as an application example?

*Related link*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your reference states, it is sometimes used to count the $k$-element multisets from a base set of size $n$. E.g. $\left( \binom{10}{12} \right)$ counts the (essentially different) ways in which you can pick up a dozen assorted donouts if the store carries 10 different types of donuts. If the store carries just one type, it is $\left( \binom{1}{12} \right) = 1$, if they carry two, it is $\left( \binom{2}{12} \right) = 13$ (from 0 of the first type to 12 of it), and so on.

Not very common, but not unheard of either. And the notation isn't exactly standard.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your very valid answer. Your gravatar was not new to me...greetings to my colleague from TeX.SE. I'm asking you a kindness, if that's possible. A more substantial and detailed explanation at an elementary level. When I translate the page I can't understand the reason for using the symbol in my question. I'll give thanks properly.

Comment: @Sebastiano, the reason for the notation is that it is (vaguely) similar to the binomial coefficients ($\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of $k$ element subsets of an $n$ set; $\left( \binom{n}{k} \right)$ is the number of $k$ element *multisets* out of an $n$ element set). A multiset  (sometimes also called a *bag*) is somewhat like a set, but an element can belong to it several times.

Comment: Please, with a lot of courtesy, can you delete the comment and edit your answer? Can you done an simplest example?